# calculating aggregate confidence intervals for forecasts

Tags: r, regression, forecasting, confidence-interval

I'm using ARIMA models to estimate sales forecast for a company. The company's sales channel is broken down into 4 sales channels and I'm running 4 different models to estimate the sales for each channel. Eventually, I'm going to aggregate the sales of these channels to find the total forecasted sales for the whole company. My questions is, how should i go about finding the confidence interval for the overall forecast? Adding up the confidence intervals of each channel is not correct since that will give me a very large interval.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can give me some idea on how to approach this sort of issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide an example of your data, attempted code, and desired output?

Comment: Since the models are different and your looking for total sales adding up the intervals makes the most sense, as it will give you the answer to 'what if all 4 of my model predictions are tending towards a particular direction of the intervals at the same time?'... But if you are not a very risk averse person I would suggest you take the 'maximum interval' as your overall interval. I am not sure if there is a better way to do this which is more statistically sound... I'd ask this question on cross validated if were you

Comment: Thanks guys! adding up the confidence interval definitely is a conservative approach. However I feel that the channels will be somewhat correlated and the overall interval will be narrower. But im not sure how to go about calculating it.

Answer (score 3):

The confidence interval is based on the variance. For a 95% interval, it is the forecast plus/minus 1.96*sqrt(variance). So you need to estimate the variance of the sum. It is not equal to the sum of the variances unless the four channels are uncorrelated. You will need to compute the correlations between the four channels, and then use the equation for the variance of a sum (check any intro stats book).